# How to persist data in a Service Worker

Tags: javascript, local-storage, indexeddb, web-worker, service-worker

As of now, Chrome does not support passing additional data to push notifications received from GCM. So I have to execute a `fetch` from my Service Worker whenever I receive a push notification. So far, so good.

**But:** I need to include a request parameter in my http request executed in `fetch`. How do I tell the service worker my parameter?

**What I've tried so far**

Using `postMessage` to tell my Service Worker the request parameter:

```
var serviceWorkerData = {};

self.addEventListener('message', function (evt) 
{
    console.log('service worker received', evt.data);

    serviceWorkerData = evt.data.myData;
});

self.addEventListener('push', function(event)
{
    event.waitUntil
    (
        fetch("http://my.url", {
            method: 'post',
            body: 'myData=' + serviceWorkerData
        }).then(function(response)
        {
            //...
        })
    );
});
```

**Why this is not working**

But this is not persistent, i.e. after I close my browser and open it again, my `serviceWorkerData` is lost. `localStorage` is not available within service workers, so how do I get persistence here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use IndexedDB.

https://github.com/mozilla/localForage if you want a simpler interface for IndexedDB.

You can import the localForage lib in a service worker using importScripts, see for example: https://github.com/marco-c/mercurius/blob/master/static/sw-push.js.